# Antrid for Lotus Notes?

Tags: ibm-domino

RPSystems seem to no longer exist, as does their utility antrid to change lotus domino replica ids.

Whilst this is not a std admin question, this is a utility used by (almost) every Notes Administrator, hence my post here.

Anyone know where to find this great utility used by many Lotus Domino Admins?

A

Comment: ANTRID is being re-released soon as a free tool. facebook.com/antridtool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a utility from http://www.ytria.com called ScanEZ. That does the trick.

Much faster than doing a File > New Copy for a db 55Gb in size.

Comment: Here is a good document about ScanEZ and changing IDs: http://techlab.ytria.com/787/lotus-notes-secrets/changereplicaid/

Comment: There is a new version of anrtid now, working for 9.0.1 - www.antrid.net